# pip{version} install --upgrade pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have multiple versions of pip and python on my CentOS. When I type `pip2.7 install --upgrade pip` it becomes clear that `pip2.7` is trying to upgrade a different version of pip as the path to the pip it is trying to upgrade is not the same as the path yielded by `which pip2.7`

How do I make pip upgrade the proper pip and not the 2.6 pip?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by upgrading pip, making my 2.6 pip utilize python 2.7 instead. For whatever reason, both pip and pip2.7 were upgraded. Then I reinstalled pip using yum package manager so it is now 2.6